# Sort de um arquivo .csv à partir da coluna numérica

Tags: python, python-3.x, classificação

Tenho o seguinte arquivo:

```
es;548
la;1832
primera;35
vez;107
que;2598
hago;15
un;878
pedido;642
y;1713
creo;83
ha;207
funcionado;1
muy;371
bien;257
los;1054
precios;88
fuesen;11
```

E gostaria de ordená-lo a partir da coluna numérica, do maior para o menor. Tentei isso, mas nao esta dando certo:

```
with open ("FREQ.csv", "r") as f:
    dados = f.read()
    colunas = dados.split(";")

    print (sorted (dados[1], key = int, reverse = True))
```

Comment: Um arquivo CSV é um arquivo que tem um numero fixo de colunas e várias linhas que seguem a mesma estrutura. No seu caso parece ser apenas um arquivo texto com apenas uma linha que tem dados separados por ponto-e-virgula. Pode colocar na pergunta um exemplo de saída correta dessa linha do arquivo?

Comment: Esta certo. Ele colocou apenas uma linha do arquivo CSV.

Comment: Mas o que você quis dizer com  'não esta dando certo', o que, de fato, acontece?

Comment: Eu tenho esta mensagem:

/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/janaina/Bureau/Lexique/Python/sort_freq.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/janaina/Bureau/Lexique/Python/sort_freq.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (sorted (dados[1], key = int, reverse = True))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @Pagotti eu tenho exatamente um arquivo CSV (nao fui eu que o criei), o problema é que nao consigo colocar aqui do jeito que ele é (duas colunas).

Comment: @pitanga você não precisa colocar o arquivo exato na questão. Apenas atualize a pergunta com um exemplo de dados (pode ser 2 linhas do arquivo) e um exemplo de como você espera que seja a saída. A forma como você está colocando a questão está confusa.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o módulo `csv` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html)

Realizei os testes utilizando python3.

```
import csv


with open ("freq.csv", "r") as f:
    dados = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    # Com o arquivo lido pelo módulo csv é possível convertê-lo em uma lista
    lista = list(dados)
    # Ordenação da lista gerada considerando o segundo elemento em ordem decrescente.
    lista_ordenada = sorted (lista, key = lambda dado: int(dado[1]), reverse = True)

    for x in lista_ordenada:
      print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira mais simples de fazer isto é separar todas as linhas do csv `\n` e após isto separar todas as colunas do csv `;`. Após agregar todas as linhas e colunas em uma lista basta dar um sort na coluna esperada, você pode usar o `lambda` e "personalizar" o método de ordenação, segue:

```
colunas = list([dado.strip().split(";") for dado in dados.strip().split("\n")])
colunas.sort(key=lambda linha: int(linha[1]), reverse=True)
print(colunas)
```

ou ainda em vez de dar o `colunas.sort...` você pode usar o `sorted`:

```
print(sorted(colunas, key=lambda linha: int(linha[1]), reverse=True))
```